# How to activate smoothState.js only on certain links

Tags: ajax, hyperlink, pjax, smoothstate.js

I know that there is a way to disable smoothState.js for some links by adding:

```
blacklist: '.no-smoothState'
```

But is there a way to disable it for every link and then selectively pick the links you want to activate smoothState.js on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
anchors: 'a.smoothState',
forms: 'form.smoothState'
```

I tried that a few weeks ago, back then it did not work, now it does.